# new to maven archtype generate

Tags: java, windows, maven, unix

I am learning to use maven atm and for some reason I am running into this error.  I am currently following Java Brain's Maven tutorial and when I enter the command mvn archtype:generate.  It starts to download all the plug in but it skips the part where I enter Choose a number or apply filter and goes right into searching a project.

```
Matt@El_Laptop ~/my_app
$ mvn archtype:generate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml   
(22 KB at 34.9 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
metadata.xml (13 KB at 19.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.377 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-06-28T16:02:14-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/94M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archtype' in the current project and in the plugin 
groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories    
[local (C:\Users\Matt\.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -  
> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]   
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is called **archetype** (not archtype).